# Fastest way to setup a new windows install

Tags: installation, windows-8.1, slipstream

Is there a way I can install windows on a VM play with it for a while, install the apps I need, then take that instance and install it on the actual hardware?

I have done slipstream before, but find for just a single install it doesn't save any time, and takes a while to make. It was about 5 years ago I did this. Are there better tools for this now?

Any other suggestions?

Comment: You forgot to mention which version of Windows.

Comment: Oops, I am actually playing with '10', but don't expect many tools to support that. So lets say 8.1.

Comment: This is not best place for jokes like this ;) There is no such thing like Windows 10. I allowed myself to edit your tags according to your comment above.

Comment: @Kamil umm.. I think you need to keep up with the [news](http://blogs.windows.com/bloggingwindows/2014/09/30/announcing-windows-10/) Apparently, they are skipping '9'.

Comment: Oh dear. I have to unsubscribe few newsletters.